# How to write function neatly? considering log, one return, no more indentation?

Tags: c++, logging, return, goto

There is a function Foo. Foo first calls Bar(), and then some statements, then Walk(), then some statements, then Run(), then some statements, then Fly(), then some statements.

Besides I'm not allowed to use exception in my code. Because the code standard in my company. :(

There are several ways, I can write Foo(), as I show below. Some are clean but not safe; some are really ugly somehow, but record all the logs. I am really  confused about this.

Which one is best, and do you have a better idea?

Can anyone help me?

I have thought about this problem from five directions: (clean[no unnecessary indentation]), (one return), (no goto), (print log), (check return value). But I am still confused. Is goto really a problem? Is it necessary to log everything?

fig1
Pros: Clean.
Cons: no log & doesn't check return value.

```
int Foo()
{
    Bar();
    // aStatement;
    Walk();
    // bStatement;
    Run();
    // cStatement;
    Fly();
    // dStatement;
    return;
}
```

fig2
Pros: clean & logs.
Cons: Multi return.

```
int Foo() {
    int status;
    status = Bar();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        return status;
    }
    // aSatement
    status = Walk();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        return status;
    }
    // bStatement
    status = Run();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        return status;
    }
    // cStatement
    status = Fly();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        return status;
    }
    // dSatement
    return status;
}
```

fig3
Pros: clean & logs.
Cons: goto problem.

```
int Foo() {
    int status;
    status = Bar();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        goto RETLINE;
    }
    // aSatement
    status = Walk();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        goto RETLINE;
    }
    // bStatement
    status = Run();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        goto RETLINE;
    }
    // cStatement
    status = Fly();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        goto RETLINE;
    }
    // dSatement
RETLINE:
    return status;
}
```

fig4
Pros: uses do while, no multi return.
Cons: more indentation.

```
int Foo() {
    int status;

    do {
        status = Bar();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            break;
        }
        // aStatement
        status = Walk();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            break;
        }
        status = Run();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            break;
        }
        // cStatement
        status = Fly();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            break;
        }
        // dStatement
    } while(false);
    return status;
}
```

fig 5
Pros: clean & one return.
Cons: no log.

```
int Foo() {
    int status;
    status = Bar();
    if (Ok(status)) {
        status = Walk();
        // aStatement
    }
    if (OK(status)) {
        // bStatement
        status = Run();
    }
    if (OK(status)) {
        // cStatement
        status = Fly();
    }
    if (Ok(status)) {
        // dStatement
    }
    return status;
}
```

fig 6
Pros: log & one return.
Cons: more indentation.

```
int Foo() {
    int status;

    status = Bar();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
    }
    if (Ok(status)) {
        // aStatement
        status = Walk();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
        }
    }
    if (OK(status)) {
        // bStatement
        status = Run();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
        }
    }
    if (Ok(status)) {
        // cStatement
        status = Fly();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
        }
    }
    if (Ok(status)) {
        // dStatement
    }
    return status;
}
```

fig7
Pros: log & one return.
Cons: more indentation.

```
int Foo() {
    bool flag = true;
    int status;
    status = Bar();
    if (!OK(status)) {
        Log("...");
        flag = false;
    }
    if (flag) {
        // aStatement
        status = Walk();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        // bStatement
        status = Run();
        if (!OK(status)) {
            Log("...");
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    if (flag) {
        // cStatement
        status = Fly();
        if (!Ok(status)) {
            Log("...");
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        // dStatment
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: You tagged this C++, so I'm just going to leave a word here: "exceptions".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I'm going to leave another word here: "log".

Comment: @avakar: What does that have to do with anything? You can log in the exception handler, that's what OP is doing, except in a silly C way.

Comment: I would not consider multiple return a con. It often does lead to cleaner code and does not require jumping through hoops in cases like this.

Comment: @Fernandes: I always heard that exception should be 'exceptional' which is not really the case here. but yes (and so +1)

Comment: Since you tagged it C++ and not Pascal the multi-return version is the most appropriate (at least from the versions you listed), except for the first one maybe.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use exception in my code. Because the code standard in my company. :(

Comment: `I'm not allowed to use exception in my code. Because the code standard in my company. :(` Umm, what? Seriously? What company? I don't want any piece of software that your company writes.

Answer (score 3):

This is tagged C++ so just use exceptions and you can write version one wrapped in a `try`/`catch`.

If this is a third party library or actually C code and you *have* to use return codes, then I think option 2 is sane. Multiple return statements aren't inherently evil if they clearly indicate the code flow.

Another approach is to wrap the call and return code check into a template that throws:

```
template <class Callee>
void DoCall(Callee callee)
{
    if(!OK(callee())) throw whatever_exception;
}
```

Comment: Besides I'm not allowed to use exception in my code. Because the code standard in my company. :(

Comment: And callee will have different input arguments

Answer (score 0):

I use the rule: effectiveness first, then robustness, then maintainability, then when needed efficiency: never sacrifice logging for cleaner code.  When your application doesn't walk (or run or fly) in some circumstance, you need the log.

From the proposals, I would suggest using early returns, but in combination with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), so there is no need for cleanup in the function.  This is very close to using exceptions.

BTW: using goto to have a single exit point to clean up is not really bad, but not needed anymore when using RAII.

Comment: At first you don't know when and where your application doesn't work， If you don't have log, It's hard to find the bugs. You mean I don't need to log? Or when the program doesn't run, Then I log ?

Comment: @xiaoming: You must log.  it might seem unnecessary when everything is alright, but when problem reports come in, you need the log.  Logging is for effectiveness and robustness, clean code is for maintainability.  So if there is confusion in my answer: LOG, then make clean code.

Answer (score 0):

As all of your function have the same signature you can wrap the call and status check in a function and chain everything with an &&.

```
int try_or_log(int (*f) (), const char** message) {
       status = (*f)();
       if(!Ok(status) {
          Log(message);
       return status;
}

int Foo() 
{
    return try_or_log(&Bar, "...") &&
        try_or_log(&Walk, "...") &&
        try_or_log(&Fly, "...");
}
```

(My C++ is rusty so that might not compile)
Otherwise that seems a good candidate for a Monad so you might be able to write an object the code will look like (that might deserve a Google 'Monda in C++'

```
int Foo() {
  Status status;
  status << &Bar << "..." << &Walk << "I don't walk" << &Fly << "I don't fly";
  return status.status;
}
```

(In fact you'll probably need 2 classes so the << operator will return one or the other class depending of the input (a function or a log message).

Comment: Unfortunately, try is a C++ keyword and thus not a valid method name.

Comment: @Ethereal my C++ is rusty indeed ;-)

Comment: OMG you used the M-word! Why are you scaring people away? ;)

Comment: I realized the 'exception' you said are indeed the Monad way to do it.

Comment: In fact Bar Walk Fly are the faked function, In the real world They may have different argument.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use #2. I don't think exiting a function on failure complicates the path of execution enough to justify any of the other methods you outlined. Logging is up to you. More complicated things take more logging. Maybe you can move the logs into the functions that might fail?
Have you considered exceptions?

Definitely don't use the break loop trick. That makes it appear that you're looping when really you're just creating a scope.

I'm not 100% against goto. It's come in handy for quick fixes, but I wouldn't engineer code around it's use.

The flag seems like just extra baggage for something simple.

Whatever convention you decide stick to it,

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able or don't want to use exceptions, I would just go with fig2 or fig7. I have never seen a good argument against multiple returns in a method, and it does everything else you seem to want, but if you dislike that approach or you have a style guide that prohibits it, then using a flag is acceptable, despite creating an unnecessary variable for something so simple.

Using `do something() while(false)` seems silly, as you are not using the loop.

Some people get very religious about `goto`, so it is better to avoid it unless you have no other choice, even if only to avoid arguments. It isn't inherently evil but it may be safer to assume that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you must check return values, then approach 1 will not suffice.

Approach 2 is acceptable.

Approach 3 is an obscenity.

Approaches 4-7 are just approach 2, overcomplicated to avoid multiple `return`s, which are really not that bad.

Consider exceptions, if you are allowed to modify `Bar()`, `Walk()` and so on. Exceptions behave differently from this code, in that `Foo`'s return value can be ignored by the caller, while an exception cannot; that might suit your purposes or it might not.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use exception in my code. Because the code standard in my company. :(